# Putting images in assets directory (android)

Tags: android, android-assets

I'm developing an application that uses a deck of cards, so I have many PNG images in my application. In an attempt to make the files more manageable - I put them in the assets directory in sub directories.
I'm wondering if this will any performance issues, as opposed to putting the images in res/drawable.
I realize that they will not be accessible through the R file, but is that just a convenience for coding, or will I be taking a performance hit?

If it will cause performance issues, how are applications with many image files generally organized? Are all of the image files just put into the res/drawable directory (with no support for subdirectories)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This method copies images from assets folder to your Sdcard .here Jaydeep's Folder is the name of my folder on sdcard.You can use your folder name in that place.

```
public void copyImagesInSdcard()
{
    assetManager = mycontext.getAssets();
    assetManager1 = mycontext.getAssets();
    System.out.println("In copyImagesInSdcard");
    try 
    {
        str1=assetManager.list("");
        ss=assetManager1.list(str1[1]);
        InputStream is;
        //System.out.println(ss[0]);
        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Jaydeep's Folder");
        if(file.exists()!=true)
        {
        file.mkdir();
        }
        else
        {
            if(file.length()==0)
            {
                file.mkdir();
            }
            System.out.println("Length:"+file.length());
        }

            for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
            {
            is=assetManager1.open(str1[1] + "/" + ss[i]);


            file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Jaydeep's Folder/" + ss[i] );

            FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file);
            //Bitmap bi = BitmapDrawable.createFromStream(is,ss[0]);


            byte b[] =new byte[4096];
            while (is.read(b) != -1) {

                out.write(b);
                }
                out.close();        
            }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only performance issue is it will always be slower to work with images from the SD Card (will, maybe "always" is too strong of a word, but certainly is true currently).